# Python sort dict by last time changing value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am writing messenger for website.
So, I have some function sequence.
First is

```
def get_messages(self):
    """select query"""
    messages = self.model.load(['or', ('sender', self.my_id), ('receiver', self.my_id)])
    return messages
```

Returns all records from database table with messages, where I am sender or receiver of message.
Next func is

```
def get_dialogs(self):
    """returns dialogs of curr user"""
    dialogs = {}
    for msg in self.messages:            
        if msg['receiver'] != self.my_id:
            tmp_d = msg['receiver']
        else:
            tmp_d = msg['sender']

        if tmp_d not in dialogs.keys():
            dialogs[tmp_d] = [msg]
        else:
            dialogs[tmp_d].append(msg)

    return dialogs
```

Here I am preparing dict, where key is user with whom I spoke.
There the problem is start.
Here is screenshot of messages sequence.
[image]

I wish the dict key sequence will be sequence sorted by last message added to value list.
Here, where I'm not sorting it, one problem actually is (problem that i can't understand) - key sequence by default should be `1, 4, 222595, 99` but program think that is `99, 1, 222595, 4` (I checked that `get_messages` func return messages in correct sequence.

**Main question**
**How can I sort dict keys** (or get sorted dicti know that dict can't be sorted) **by last time value was changed?**

Comment: I suppose, you want to use a datatype that allows sorting, e.g. a list. You can sort them by defining a comparison function and the builtin sort() function. Besides there are ordered dicts, that keep the order of data put into them: http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Comment: Make an order by time desc in your sql query

Comment: Unrelated tip: don't use `key in dictionary.keys()`; that is very inefficient as that creates a new list with all keys where searching is costly (Python 2) or a dictionary view object (Python 3). Use `key in dictionary` instead. Or in this case, don't test for the key but use `dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict`s in Python are *unsorted* - the keys do not appear in any particular order.

Consider using a `collections.OrderedDict` from the standard library instead. `OrderedDict` keeps your items sorted by insertion time (i.e. based on the order in which the items were added to the dict).

Update: if you’re using Python 3.6+, dicts are now sorted by insertion order. This behaviour is guaranteed in Python 3.7+ (in Python 3.6, it is true simply because the interpreter is built that way).

Answer (score 1):

You could checkout [`RevisionDict`](https://pypi.org/project/revisiondict/). It remembers the order when keys were *updated* (in contrast to the OrderedDict which is remembering the order when keys are *inserted*). The interface of a `RevisionDict` is 100% compatible to a `dict`.

```
>>> d['a']=0; d['b']=1; d['c']=2  # make three updates
>>> d
RevisionDict([_Item(key='a', value=0, revision=1),
              _Item(key='b', value=1, revision=2),
              _Item(key='c', value=2, revision=3)])
>>> d['a']=3                      # update value of 'b' (was 2 before)
>>> d
RevisionDict([_Item(key='b', value=1, revision=2),
              _Item(key='c', value=2, revision=3),
              _Item(key='a', value=3, revision=4)])
```

*Disclosure*: I'm the author of that library.